# i don't understand what's wrong, this is a basic load balancer in go

Tags: go, http, backend, reverse-proxy

When I run the program, the output comes like this

```
1
2
7
8
```

Server serving at 'http://localhost:3000'

On visiting the localhost:3000/ I get the 404, nothing gets printed on terminal and the server also doesn't crash.

I used fmt.Printf() in various functions to check if the control is going into the function or not and seems like the control never entered the handleRedirect() function

I tried but I'm unable to figure out the issue, I just started learning go land some time ago

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
    "os"
)

type Server interface {
    Address() string
    IsAlive() bool
    Serve(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
}

type SimpleServer struct {
    address string
    proxy   *httputil.ReverseProxy
}

func newSimpleServer(address string) *SimpleServer {
    serverURL, err := url.Parse(address)
    handleError(err)

    return &SimpleServer{
        address: address,
        proxy:   httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(serverURL),
    }
}

type LoadBalancer struct {
    port            string
    roundRobinCount int
    servers         []Server
}

func newLoadBalancer(port string, servers []Server) *LoadBalancer {
    return &LoadBalancer{
        port:            port,
        roundRobinCount: 0,
        servers:         servers,
    }
}

func (s *SimpleServer) Address() string { return s.address }
func (s *SimpleServer) IsAlive() bool   { return true }
func (s *SimpleServer) Serve(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(6)
    s.proxy.ServeHTTP(rw, r)
}

func (lb *LoadBalancer) getNextAvailableServer() Server {
    server := lb.servers[lb.roundRobinCount%len(lb.servers)]
    for !server.IsAlive() {
        lb.roundRobinCount++
        server = lb.servers[lb.roundRobinCount%len(lb.servers)]
    }
    lb.roundRobinCount++
    return server
}

func (lb *LoadBalancer) ServeProxy(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(4)
    targetServer := lb.getNextAvailableServer()
    fmt.Printf("forwarding reques to %q\n", targetServer.Address())
    fmt.Println(5)
    targetServer.Serve(rw, r)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(1)
    servers := []Server{
        newSimpleServer("https://www.fast.com/"),
        newSimpleServer("https://www.theverge.com/"),
        newSimpleServer("https://www.canva.com/"),
    }

    fmt.Println(2)
    lb := newLoadBalancer("3000", servers)
    handleRedirect := func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println(3)
        lb.ServeProxy(rw, req)
    }
    
    fmt.Println(7)
    http.HandleFunc("/", handleRedirect)
    
    fmt.Println(8)
    fmt.Printf("server serving at 'http://localhost:%s'\n", lb.port)
    http.ListenAndServe(":"+lb.port, nil)
}

func handleError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("you've got an error fix it asap %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you must not increment roundRobinCount without synchronization. That's a data race.

Comment: i won't lie that i didn't understood what you just said but i'll do searching for it, thanks

Comment: Your server is going to handle the path `/` so if you are not seeing any "forwarding" output you have something wrong outside of this code. Also the target servers here are going to reject these requests, so you are always going to get a 4xx response.

Comment: understood i'll do that